# Laravel Can't upload file on server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file-upload

I can upload file image in my local, but can't upload in the production server.

the error message that i got in the server :

```
ErrorException in AttachableTrait.php line 125: Non-static method Illuminate\Log\Writer::error() should not be called statically
```

my function in the AttachableTrait.php:

```
public function processAttachment()
{
    try {
        foreach (array_keys($this->getAttachableFields()) as $field) {
            $dirpath = $this->generateUploadRelativePath($field);
            if (is_string($this->$field)) {
                $this->$field = ltrim($this->$field, '/');
            }

            if (!$this->isDirty($field)) {
                continue;
            }

            $inputValue = $this->getAttributeFromArray($field);
            if (empty($inputValue)) {
                $this->setAttribute($field, null);
                continue;
            }

            $attachment = Attachment::download($inputValue, $dirpath);

            $this->assignAttachmentField($field, $attachment);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exc) {
        \Log::error('Error download ' . $exc->getMessage());         ----> line 125
    }
}
```

some .env configuration in the server :

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_URL=https://myApplication.com/
```

some configuration in filesystem.php :

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('/app'),
    ],

    'local-storage' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path(),
    ],

    'local-root' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => '/root',
    ],

],
```

is there maybe an incorrect configuration file ?

Comment: use `logger()->error("Error download ' . $exc->getMessage()");`   it is getting wrong class `Illuminate\Log\Writer`

Comment: how to solve it? should I add `use Illuminate \ Log \ Writer;` ?

Comment: You are using a wrong class, it should be `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log`